# CSS on device different to browser

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2

i am using Ionic2 and have an app that has messages. the message looks as follows in a **browser**:

[image]

However, running on an **Android** or **iOS** device, it looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the tail on each message is missing.

**Question**

If anyone can advise how I can get the style to be consistent and display the tail on all devices?

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding class="messages-page-content">
    <ion-list class="message-list">
      <ion-item class="message-item" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async">
        <div [ngClass]="{'message message-me':(item.memberId1 == me.uid)}">
          <div [ngClass]="{'message message-you':(item.memberId1 == you.uid)}">
            <div class="message-content">{{item.message_text}}</div>
            <span class="time-tick">
                        <span class="message-timestamp-date">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YY'}}</span>
            <span class="message-timestamp">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
            <div *ngIf="item.memberId1 === me.uid && item.readByReceiver === true">
              <span class="checkmark">
                                <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
                                <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
                            </span>
            </div>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**CSS**

See: `background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);` and `background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png);`

```
.title-timestamp {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: gray;
}

.message-item {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.label {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}

.message-send {
  font-size: 3.2em;
}

.input-wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
}

.item-md.item-block .item-inner {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.messages-page-navbar {
  .chat-picture {
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  .chat-title {
    line-height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .chat-subtitle {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

.messages-page-content {
  > scroll-content {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .message-list {
    background-color: #E0DAD6;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .message-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 9px;

    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }

  .message {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 236px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

    &.message-me {
      float: right;
      background-color: #effeff;

      &::before {
        right: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);
      }
    }

    &.message-you {
      float: left;
      background-color: #FFF;

      &::before {
        left: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png);
      }
    }

    &.message-you::before, &.message-me::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 3px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 19px;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .message-content {
      padding: 5px 7px;
      word-wrap: break-word;

      &::after {
        content: " \00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
        display: inline;
      }
    }

    .message-timestamp {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 2px;
      right: 17px;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: gray;
    }

    .message-timestamp-date {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 2px;
      right: -6px;
      font-size: 9px;
      color: gray;
    }
  }
}

.message-datetime {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: grey;
}

.messages-page-footer {
  padding-right: 0;

  .message-editor {
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .message-editor-button {
    background: color($colors, primary);
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

.checkmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height:22px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 1px;
}

.checkmark_stem {
    position: absolute;
    width:2px;
    height:9px;
    background-color:#3BB9FF;
    left:15px;
    top:6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
    position: absolute;
    width:2px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#3BB9FF;
    left:13px;
    top:12px;
}

.time-tick {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the advise below, I add the following:

**CSS**

```
  .tail-me {
    background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -11px
  }

  .tail-you {
    background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -11px
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item class="message-item tail-me" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async">
```

And it displays this in the **browser**:

[image]

As you can see, the tail is in the wrong position.  If I make the position: absolute, it throws the message out totally. The `left` and `bottom` css attributes move the message bubbles. So I am guessing I am putting the `tail-me` on the wrong tag in the html. Any ideas?

On an **iOS** and **Android** device, it still does not display the tail:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Android and iOS versions don't process pseudo elements correctly. I would try another method such as creating a class element that is placed in .message-me and .message-you.

Append that class element to each message box, and add an absolute positioning to it so that it's:

```
.tail-me {
    background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -11px
}
```

and

```
.tail-you {
    background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -11px
}
```

An absolutely positioned element inside of a relatively positioned element (your .message), will be placed inside of that relative position element.

Comment: Thanks!  But where should the `tail-me` and `tail-you` class go in the `html`?

Comment: If I add the `tail-me` and `tail-you` class inside the same `div`, i.e. `'message message-me tail-me'`, then it has the image repeating over the message bubble.

Comment: the `.tail-me` and `.tail-you` can go anywhere in the div since they're being absolutely positioned. Absolutely positioned divs don't have a relative positioning to other divs. Whatever positioning you set for them, they'll be in that spot. So since it's set to `bottom: 0` and `left: -11px` then it'll be there regardless of any other element's positioning in the div.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding it as a class in addition to the other classes of the div. Rather, just add a `<div class="tail-me"></div>` inside of your `message message-me` element.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake on my part. It does work on a devise. The issue was the path to the image was incorrect, so the devise was not picking up the image.

Was:

```
background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);
```

Should be:

```
background-image: url(../assets/message-me.png);
```